# Matching multiple different start and end of line in one multiline regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to match multiple lines with my regex, which is operating in multiline mode.  As far as I can tell, though, the Regex parser is not capable of dealing with more than one line at a time with respect to the regex when in multiline mode.  So this for example does not match:

```
Regex: ^Line1$^Line2$
```

For this text:

```
Line1
Line2
```

How can I match both lines, being explicit about the start and end of the lines?  Do I have to use a nasty construct like `(\r\n|\r|\n)` to try and match the newline style of whatever system I'm running on, or is there a better way?

Comment: You forgot to match the line break, `^Line1(?>\r\n?|\n)Line2$` or `(?m)^Line1(?>\r\n?|\n)Line2\r?$`

Comment: That's the point; I don't want to match the line break with explicit characters, I want to semantically use the "beginning of line" and "end of line" characters to avoid specifying a system-specific end of line sequence.

Comment: There is no way, there is no even `\R` construct support in C# regex. `^` and `$` are zero-width assertions, they do not consume any text so after `Line1` your regex can't and won't find `Line2`, there are line break chars to consume.